# Angular date object setting hour causes date to be day before

Tags: angular, datetime

When I run these two lines:

```
date_obj = new Date('2018-08-23');
date_obj.setHours('19');
```

The output I get is:

```
2018-08-23T00:00:00.000Z
```

And then:

```
2018-08-22T23:00:00.000Z
```

I understand that it's being changed to UTC time in the second one hence the hour being 23 and not 19 like it was set to. So my question is why is it changing it to the day before and how can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) with a string argument creates a UTC date. If you are in GMT-0400 (Eastern), calling `new Date('2018-08-23')` results in:

```
Eastern: 2018-08-22 20:00:00
GMT:     2018-08-23 00:00:00
```

When you call `Date.setHours(19)`, you set the hours [according to local time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), which results in:

```
Eastern: 2018-08-22 19:00:00
GMT:     2018-08-22 23:00:00
```

---

You could create a date for local time with the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) that accepts multiple arguments:

```
let date = new Date(2018, 7, 23); // Note: the month index starts at zero
```

which gives:

```
Eastern: 2018-08-23 00:00:00
GMT:     2018-08-23 04:00:00
```

Then call `Date.setHours(19)` to get:

```
Eastern: 2018-08-23 19:00:00
GMT:     2018-08-23 23:00:00
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vypwvu) for a demo.

Comment: So this does work and thank you for the explanation as to why what happened was happening. But when I create a new date like `new Date(2018, 8, 23)` it says that the month is September? As an example when I `.toISOString()` the date object it returns the month as 9

Comment: Oh yes, I will correct that. With that Date constructor, the `monthIndex` starts at zero.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you what you want:

```
new Date(new Date('2018-08-23').setHours(19))
```

Here's various outputs from my console:

```
new Date('2018-08-23')
```

Thu Aug 23 2018 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

```
new Date('2018-08-23').setHours('19')
```

1535047200000

```
new Date('2018-08-23').setHours(19)
```

1535047200000

```
new Date(new Date('2018-08-23').setHours(19))
```

Thu Aug 23 2018 19:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

It appears setHours is returning a timestamp not a Date, so you need to create a new Date from the timestamp.

Alternatively, use the moment.js library, its a lot easier to work with.